Proof about Hadamard matrices that $H H^\textsf{T} = n I_n$
I have read the Wikipedia article about Hadamard matrices that says:
Let $H$ be a Hadamard matrix of order $n$, the following is true: $H H^\textsf{T} = n I_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity $n×n$ matrix.
I want to know what's the reason for this to be true. Additionally, I want to see the graphical proof and the step-by-step proof, not just “$H H^\textsf{T} = n I_n$ is simply true”.
Source: Wikipedia

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Well, since rows of $H$ are orthogonal, rows of $H$ and column of $H^T$ are orthogonal... the claim almost follows....

Notice that the rows of $H$ are all orthogonal vectors over the field of real numbers, and each has length $\sqrt {n}$, so if you observe the $HH^{T}$ calculation, you will get $nI_n$. Because if $u$ is a orthogonal vector with length $\sqrt{n}$, then $u\cdot u = ||u||^2 = n$ and $u \cdot v = 0$ for all other rows vector $v$.

Thank you for the answer. However, I'm not a math university student, I'm just a math lover, and I don't understand what are orthogonal vectors.

I gave you the definition, but you can see the definition. It is very simple. For example let {u,v,w} is an orthogonal set of vectors then u.u that is dot product of u and u will be non zero and also v.v = w.w is non zero. But u.v = u.w = v.w = 0

That is in simple words dot product of two same elements is non zero and dot product of two different elements is zero.

Oh, I see. However, I have two questions: why is n square rooted and what is ||u||? (I know about |x|, but not ||u||)

In $\Bbb R^{n}$ if $u$ is a vector then $||u||$ is the norm of $u$, and it is defined as $||u|| = \sqrt{u \cdot u}$

I made one mistake in typing, and now it has been corrected. So with this information, you will get $HH^T$ is a diagonal matrix with each diagonal entry being $n$.
